# How do I play the haunting song?

Tags: undertale

There is a piano. And there is a music box, which [plays a little tune on loop.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_NEtpzLwck&feature=youtu.be) The game wants me to play the first 8 notes from that music box.

[image]
[image]

There is also this enemy hint: "si re si re si mi si mi". (That's B D B D B E B E for ya yanks.)

[image]
[image]

I've tried however all combinations of 8 notes that could match up these notes (such as `↑←↑←↑↓↑↓`, `↑•↑•↑←↑←`, `↓•↓•↓←↓←`, etc.) and nothing happens. If I ignore what the monster says and just try to play what I hear, I get [`↑↓↑↓•↓•↓`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KvrNiC-7uA&feature=youtu.be) — but that also doesn't work, and neither do slight variations (`•↑↓↑↓•↓•↓→`). I'm not very good at all at matching notes with sounds, or notes with notes, but what the music box plays and what I'm playing don't sound quite unlike.

What gives?

Comment: And no, `↑↑↓↓←→←→` is not it ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, Shyren's song isn't the hint for the puzzle. The statute I the room to the right plays a melody when you put an umbrella on it, and that melody is the only hint, and the notes it plays don't match what Shyren sings.

Comment: "That's B D B D B E B E for ya yanks." We use that notation in Britain too (maybe it's all English speakers?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct sequence is:

## `•↑→•↓•↓→`

(That means hit Z, Z-Up, Z-right, Z, Z-down, Z, Z-down, Z-right.)

Comment: To get the arrow keys, keep the `Z` button pressed while you enter them.

Comment: You could also add information how to figure it out: *"East of the room with Shyren is a statue being rained on. If you give it an umbrella, the music box it is holding will begin to play the song "Memory". For the piano puzzle, it requires the first 8 notes of the song"* from http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Piano_Puzzle

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it gives you the answer if you wait, in a dialog text with the statue. The only thing you need to do is memorize that.

EDIT: Turns out you don't have to be in dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was only z,z-up,z-right,z,z-down,z-down,z-right

Answer (score -1):

•↑→•↓↓→
(That means hit Z, Z-Up, Z-right, Z, Z-down, Z-down, Z-right.)

Comment: Note that this is one stroke different than the accepted answer. And this answer is essentially the same as [RamblinRose101's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/254086).