# What are the best ways to make money?

Tags: undertale

There is several expensive items in Undertale, such as the Spider Donut or the Temmie Armor, which are both worth 9999G. What are the best ways to generate such an amount of money ?

Comment: Makes you wish you'd had bought the donut earlier, doesn't it? Hehe.

Comment: The best way is to do a genocide route. It generates a **lot** of money. =P

Answer (score 14):

Three of the most common ways to generate money in Undertale involve the [Tem Shop](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Tem_Shop). If you didn't find the Temmie Village yet, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypv6_IL4SX0) will help you.

- The first way is to buy [Temmie Flakes](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Temmie_Flakes) for 1G directly to Tem. You can then sell those back for 2G.
- The second way is to use [Dog Residues](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Dog_Residue). This object can be obtained in the legendary artifact puzzle. When you use it, it fills your inventory with Dog Residue. You can then sell those in the Tem Shop for a price varying between 1 and 4G. Just keep in mind to always keep one in your inventory, so you can use it again to fill your inventory and sell those again.
- The last way involves [Cloudy Glasses](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Cloudy_Glasses). Go to [Gerson](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Gerson)'s shop, buy as much as you can for 30G each, then go back to the Tem Shop. You can then sell each one of those for at least 50G, so you have a 20G benefit for each Cloudy Glasses you sell.

Whatever is the strategy you choose, always make sure to empty your inventory to have enough place to buy all the items to sell (or in order to fill it entirely with Dog Residues). You will have to repeat the process a certain amount of time depending on the strategy you chose, but it will ultimately lead you to the amount of money you need.

Comment: Temmie Village (and thus the Tem Shop) has a slightly hidden entrance.  Basically, the room that leads to it has a puzzle... solving it opens both the way to the next area of the game, but also opens the Temmie Village entrance earlier in the same room.

Answer (score 1):

I've always just used Napstablook's snail race.. 20g profit every time your snail loses by just a little. You just encourage your snail, wait for the little exclamation mark to disappear, then encourage him again for a total of seven encouragements. Then, if he's going to win, encourage him one more time because he can't move while you're pressing the button. 
It doesn't take very long, and I prefer it to walking all over for the glasses. 
I also don't know if Blookie's always out running the race though, I always just play it a bunch right when I find it.

(I know this hasn't been posted to in a while, but I figure if I'm looking it up, someone else probably is too.)

Comment: "your small"? Do you mean "your snail"? You wrote it twice.

Comment: Well, technically ...

Answer (score 1):

Just because no one mentioned it, you could feasibly take the ferry near Waterfall.  While the ferryman will say "3 gold for the ferry"  he will pay you 3 gold for the pleasure of having you step on his face.  You seem to be able to do that infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Dog Residue and sell the Dog Residues it generates, then use it again and sell again until you get 9999g. You can only sell to Tem Shop.

Comment: or you can cheat using a memory editor like cheat engine, or a save editor.

Comment: OK aedaozkal but how do u get dog residue

Comment: @user143750 http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Dog_Residue

Comment: @user143750 [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237729/how-do-i-play-the-haunting-song?rq=1) describes the puzzle that gives you the Dog Residue.

Answer (score 0):

What they're not telling you is that there's a box right outside the store with the glasses AND a box outside temmie. The box holds 10 items. Empty it, buy 8 glasses, shove them in the box, buy 8 more, shove two of them in the box, buy two more, sell all 18 for 20 profit a piece. That's 360 gold every time. That's the equivalent of selling 450 temmie flakes for 2 gold each.

Comment: This answer does not provide new information, because top answer already mentions cloudy glasses method. You have two boxes accessible at any moment, probably, after your phone is upgraded.

Answer (score -3):

By modifying game file:

File0, change line 11 to 9999. There you go, now you have 9999 gold.